# After page has already loaded, load another image and use it to replace the page's current BackGround image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

The front page of my site has quite a big image as a background, of course I've made it as small as possible but it's still going to take a moment to load on slow connections.

So if the user stays on my site for a while I want to change that background image to another one. I've seen some of the plugins which are available to have something similar but they all seem to load the images all first. Which would be slow for my purposes

So I would like to just load the page as normal. Then after a little delay behind the scenes load another image and once it's loaded, replace the original image. Is this possible?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure set an image tag in the body like this: `<img id="bgqueue" />`

Your CSS would hide that:

```
#bgqueue {
    display : none;
}
```

And your jQuery would look something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#bgqueue').attr('src', 'http://someOtherjpg').on('load', function() {
        $('body').css({background: 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')'});
    });
}, 30000);
```

So the image is loaded into that image tag behind the scenes after 30 seconds in that example, and once it's loaded, the callback fires and sets the body background image to the cache file.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/TpPkk/

Comment: Cool, I think this indeed does the trick. I need to modify it slightly for my own purposes but it should work nicely. Thanks so much!